# Angular copies images to its root folder

Tags: angular

I keep my assets images under 'assets/images/icons' folder and in my style.scss file I have rules like 'background: url(assets/images/icons/searchbox_magnifier.png) no-repeat #f5f5f5;' but while making a production build, Angular is coping all those files to its root folder and changing style.scss rules according to it, like 'background: url(searchbox_magnifier.png)', see the images attached.

[style.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRGuD.jpg)
[production build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TejX.jpg)

How to avoid the issue?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli for build ?

Comment: Yes, ng build --prod --aot

Comment: what version of cli are you using ? is there an angular.json file or .angular-cli file ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.7.3 and there's the .angular-cli.json file under the project's root folder as well.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. It is solved simply by changing the paths from relative to absolute. 
For example, 
`background-image: url("../../../assets/images/background.svg")` 
or 
`background-image: url("~src/assets/images/background.svg")`

replace with 
`background-image: url("/assets/images/background.svg")`.

It will solve your problem

Comment: Tricky it seems when referencing / and the app is moved to a sub folder.  Doesn't seem to know about ./ or have that pathing intelligence out-of-the-box.  And if you work around this scoping issue it moves it all into the root.  It seems more anchored to where the file is, vs where HTML really loads the CSS i.e. root.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Images from assets folder, if used as relative paths in the CSS files, are COPIED to the root of the dest build.

if the path in the CSS is absolute, it does not. using absolute path solved the problem for @angry beaver  , only because his application is deployed into the root folder of his web-server.

please note, that if you use --base-href in your build, it will append it to the url inside the CSS files. thus making it a problem for doing a build that needs to be deployed to different destinations (qa/pre-prod etc) if each one is in another sub-folder (for example, qa is in the root folder, and production is in a subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

In your `.angular-cli` file please find:

```
"assets": [
   "assets",
   "favicon.ico"
]
```

as your defaults.

According to `./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`, assets accept:

```
"assets": {
        "type": "array",
        "description": "List of application assets.",
        "items": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "glob": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "default": "",
                  "description": "The pattern to match."
                },
                "input": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "default": "",
                  "description": "The dir to search within."
                },
                "output": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "default": "",
                  "description": "The output path (relative to the outDir)."
                },
                "allowOutsideOutDir": {
                  "type": "boolean",
                  "description": "Allow assets to be copied outside the outDir.",
                  "default": false
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
          ]
        },
```

So in your case please try changing to:

```
"assets": [
   ...
   {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./assets",
      "output": "assets/"
   }
 ]
```

or wherever you want them to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to implement your code but I got an issue with it, I couldn't make a build as there were many errors in console, then I just changed my css code from url(assets/images/icons/searchbox_magnifier.png) to url('/assets/images/icons/searchbox_magnifier.png') and now it makes a build as it supposed to.

Comment: Well I didn't do much then :) Glad you've solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your CSS files from 
"styles" :  [
"path to css"
]

In angular.json file.

Add all those css files references in index.html

Images referred in css and if that css files are bundled, then all those images get copied to build folder.